# Label Text Alignment not pragmatically

Tags: ios7, swift2, xcode7

Hi I am trying to justify the text of a label in a table view cell with autolayout, but I am unable, the text is always align to the left. I have been reading some posts in this forum but they are only for pragmatically use.
Any help is more than welcome :)

[image]

Comment: I think we need more info on the problem. But try add lines (below the alignment) to see if the problem is fixed. If you do not resolve, post more information, like a preview of your screen and update your question that I will try to help you.

Comment: There is nothing to add, it is a simple Label in a Table view, I can align the text right, left and center, but for justify it shows as left align, do not justify. I have text view in other page that is able to justify. This happens only with labels in Swift 2. I drag the label from the Object Library it is not built pragmatically.

Comment: Strange, here it worked. There is a property named Lines below the Alignment property on the Panel of the Label, you made this change?

Comment: @James I selected as 0 zero. because there will be more than one line...